# GPUImage applying filters

Tags: objective-c, filter, gpuimage

I'm new in developing iOS Apps.
I would ask, whether there is a standard code to applying GPUImage Filters?

Thanks a lot for answering.

Filter error:
[image]

Undeclared Indentifier (error: Use of undeclared identifier 'brightnessFilter'):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you an example that works for me. This is a category I created on UIImage that chains together GPUImage's `GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter` and `GPUImageBrightnessFilter`:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithGaussianBlur:(UIImage *)image {

    // pass the image through a brightness filter to darken a bit and a gaussianBlur filter to blur
    GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];

    GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter *blurFilter = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc] init];
    blurFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 2;
    blurFilter.blurPasses = 1;
    [stillImageSource addTarget:blurFilter];

    GPUImageBrightnessFilter *brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
    [brightnessFilter setBrightness:-0.15f];
    [blurFilter addTarget:brightnessFilter];

    [stillImageSource processImage];
    return [brightnessFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

}
```

You may only be using a single filter at a time. If that's the case, ignore the 3 lines starting with `GPUImageBrightnessFilter`. You can find some more information here by searching for "performing common tasks" and scrolling down: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/README.md

I wanted to point out the concept of adding the second filter as a target to the first filter though, because it was a bit tricky to me at first. You may reach a point that you want to use more than one at a time. Refer to comments from Brad Larson (the creator of GPUImage) here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/233.

Hope this at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I applied the code into my project. But now I have an error. Could you have a look on it please?

Comment: @Dev_P - First, please don't just post images of errors in your questions, as they're impossible to read. Post the text of the error itself. Second, the error very clearly says that you're trying to pass a UIImageView into the method, instead of a UIImage. These are two very different things. Provide a UIImage instead.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it. Now I have an undeclared identifier (brightnessFilter) what do I have to do to eliminate the error? P.S I posted an image of the error and the code line.

Comment: @Dev_P, `brightnessFilter` is an undeclared identifier because you don't have any pointer declared with that name. You do have one called `blurFilter`... Since you are new to iOS programming, I strongly recommend spending some time reading here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html